# no positive roots for $(y+1)^{7}-2(y+1)^{5}+10(y+1)^{2}-1$

Tags: polynomials, problem-solving

Hint for showing that $(y+1)^{7}-2(y+1)^{5}+10(y+1)^{2}-1$ has no positive roots
thanks

Answer (score 7):

Expand and you see all coefficients are positive.

> $$y^7+7 y^6+19 y^5+25 y^4+15 y^3+11 y^2+17 y+8$$

If you put $y>0$ the whole sum turns out positive.

**Expanding (efficiently) the given polynomials in powers of $y$ (by hand):**

We want $q(y):=(y+1)^7−2(y+1)^5+10(y+1)^2−1=a_0+a_1y+a_2y^2+...+a_7y^7$, for some $a_0,a_1,...,a_7$.

Notice that $a_0$ is the value of the polynomial on the right evaluated at $y=0$. So we just need to evaluate the polynomial on the left at $y=0$.

This is the same as evaluating the polynomial $p(x):=x^7-2x^5+10x^2-1$ at $x=1$.

Then $(q(y)-a_0)/y=a_1+a_2y+...+a_7y^6$.

We can do the evaluation using Ruffini-Horner algorithm. The advantage is that the algorithm gives us also the coefficient of $(q(y)-a_0)/y$ written as powers of $(y+1)$. So repeating Ruffini-Horner several times we get the coefficients we wanted.

**The actual computation to be done by hand:**
(First read how Ruffini-Horner goes in Wikipedia and how the computation is written in a table).

We get the coefficients of $p(x)=1x^7+0x^6-2x^5+0x^4+0x^3+10x^2+0x-1$ and to Ruffini-Horner to evaluate $p(x)$ at $x_0=1$.

$$\begin{array}{c|rrrrrrrr}x_0&x^7&x^6&x^5&x^4&x^3&x^2&x^1&x^0\\1&1&0&-2&0&0&10&0&-1\\&&1&1&-1&-1&-1&9&9\\\hline\\&1&1&-1&-1&-1&9&9&\boxed{8}\\1&&1&2&1&0&-1&8\\\hline\\&1&2&1&0&-1&8&\boxed{17}\\1&&1&3&4&4&3\\\hline\\&1&3&4&4&3&\boxed{11}\\1&&1&4&8&12\\\hline\\&1&4&8&12&\boxed{15}\\1&&1&5&13\\\hline\\&1&5&13&\boxed{25}\\1&&1&6\\\hline\\&1&6&\boxed{19}\\1&&1\\\hline\\&1&\boxed{7}\\1&&\\\hline\\&\boxed{1}\end{array}$$

In the boxes there are the coefficients of the expansion.

Comment: This is a prep-test question, so I won't have Wolfram to expand it for me. It requires expanding all the binomials. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @TKM you don't need Wolfram to expand it for you.

Comment: how else can you expand it without using binomial formula?

Comment: I can't believe that question. To begin with, you can, in the worst case, multiply $(y+1)$ by itself two, five, and seven times. That is well inside what is possible to do by hand. I will add an even easier method. It is a shame that the method is culturally getting lost. I will add it to the answer. Learn it and teach it to as many friends you can.

Comment: With the emergence of high-speed computation, and continuing with readily-available "desktop" (and then on-line) computing and graphing, a lot of the knowledge and lore related to the "theory of equations" has fallen out of the curriculum.  (To show what it's come to, Sullivan's _Pre-calculus_, for instance, dropped reference to Descartes's Law of Signs(!) between the 8th and 9th editions...)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner It happens with everything, and it is not always a bad thing. The problem is when it is dropped not because it is not important anymore, but because of lazy writers/teachers. Descartes rule I wouldn't mind. It is not so important anyway. I have only used it successfully once. Often one gets an even number of sign changes. Descartes is relatively not as easy to prove. ...

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Ruffini-Horner, on the other hand, is just a particular case of long division. I am pretty sure they still study long division, and the remainder theorem in high school. In addition, lots of students struggle with partial fraction decomposition in first year calculus. Using Ruffini partial fractions is a piece of cake.

Answer (score 1):

Check the value at $y = 0$; look at it's derivative's value for positive $y$.

Comment: any hints on why $7(y+1)^5-10(y+1)^3+20>0$ is true $\forall y>0$? Besides calculating using binomials.

Answer (score 0):

Note that our expression is equal to
$$(y+1)^5((y+1)^2 -2)+10(y+1)^2 -1.$$
If $y\ge \sqrt{2}-1$, then the expression is safely positive, indeed pretty big.  In particular, if $y\ge 1$ then our expression is positive.

Now suppose that $0\lt y\lt 1$. We have $(y+1)^7 -2(y+1)^5 \gt -(y+1)^5$.

Note that $10(y+1)^2-1-(y+1)^5=2(y+1)^2-1 + (y+1)^2(8-(y+1)^3)$. The part $2(y+1)^2-1$ is $\gt 1$, and the part $8-(y+1)^3$ is positive, since $y\lt 1$.